# MAUI Blazor | Share Memory between C# and JavaScript, possible?

Tags: javascript, c#, maui-blazor

I'm working on app that will allocate a fixed memory chunk (20mb) since the app begin, and preserve during the app lifecycle.

and in blazor side, I required to access the memory chunk to display certain 2D/3D output with JavaScript through canvas webgl.

is it possible to configure the memory chunk to be accessible directly by JavaScript? so that no need to send the data over and over through JavaScript interop.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is it possible to configure the memory chunk to be accessible directly
> by JavaScript?

This is impossible. You cannot directly access memory from JavaScript.

Since JavaScript is an interpreted language, there is no single and conclusive answer to this question, except for: Every time you assign or change a variable, and every time you create a function, your JavaScript engine will handle assigning memory for you. The same is true for freeing up memory, when the resources are no longer needed. Every browser comes with its own JavaScript engine.

> because wasm able to create shared memory and access them between
> JavaScript or other wasm instances, so I think maybe Blazor have
> similar way to share the memory, perhaps passing a pointer using
> interop call?

This should be `WebAssembly.Memory`, which is browser memory, and if it's a pure `asp.net core blazor webAssembly` application, it might work because it's running on a browser. But Blazor in MAUI is not a `webassembly` application, it is to display Blazor in webview. So its C# code should run on the user's device and use the device's memory, so it cannot be accessed directly with JS.

Comment: because wasm able to create shared memory and access them between JavaScript or other wasm instances, so I think maybe Blazor have similar way to share the memory, perhaps passing a pointer using interop call?

thanks

Comment: how to use WebAssembly.Memory in blazor webAssembly?
was thinking may be i can turn my app core (which the calc parts) into wasm and load in webview, then should be able to command through the C# code using Jsinterop.

thank you very much